# Direct site to different server based on uri Path instead of subdomain

Tags: domain-name-system

I have a client with an asp.net site hosted in one environment.  It was proposed to them, they could point their base domain to a new WordPress site hosted somewhere else, to be easier to update without affecting the asp.net application. I was given the assumption that based on URI path, we can point to different servers from the DNS, without any use of subdomains.

for example:

> example.com, example.com/about - goes to WordPress site hosted by Hosting Company A
>
> example.com/account/*, example.com/dashboard/* - goes to asp.net site hosted by Hosting Company B

Can this be done without a subdomain, and how could it be accomplished in Network Solutions?

Sorry if this is a simple(or ridiculous) question, I normally focus on the dev side of things

Thank you!

Comment: The search term you are looking for is `reverse proxy`. It is configured in the web server you are using and has nothing to do with DNS.

Comment: I don't believe we'll have access to do the reverse proxy, neither of the servers are in our control. Both are hosted services, not full VM's giving us access to apache/nginx/iis.  So my only option is subdomains?